# Unacceptable type of value for to-one relationship: desired type = NSManagedObject; given type = NSManagedObject;

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm trying to add an object to a 'to-one' relationship:

```
//1. I create the temporary object for the ServerUpdates entity
NSManagedObject *updateObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ServerUpdates" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

//2. I make sure that obj is in the same context (note: I get obj from fetch)
obj = [self.managedObjectContext objectWithID:[obj objectID]];

//3. I then try to add the object to the key - and this is where we get the error
[updateObj setValue:obj forKey:@"fkServerUpdatesToAuthors"];
```

I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',reason:'Unacceptable type of value for to-one relationship: property ="fkServerUpdatesToAuthors"; desired type = NSManagedObject; given type =NSManagedObject; value =  (entity: Authors; id: 0x74a2290

At first I thought this was because I was trying to assign a relationship between a persistant object and a temporary object, but when I added a save between 1. and 2., I still got the same error.

> **Note:**
>   I haven't created any associated sub-classes for NSManagedObject. The relationship setup is: fkServerUpdatesToAuthors (to-one) in ServerUpdates entity INVERSE RELATIONSHIP WITH fkAuthorsToServerUpdates (to-many) in Authors entity.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the CoreData entity for ServerUpdates, re-built it and it started working.

In case others run into the same problem: I think the cause was the assignment of an an incorrect NSManagedObject to fkServerUpdatesToAuthors relationship attribute. It was expecting an 'Authors' NSManagedObject (as defined in the 'Destination' field for the relationship), but I must have been passing in something different -e.g. 'Books' (or vice versa).

The error message is unclear because I abstracted to using NSManagedObject to access the object (rather than Authors or Books subclasses), so to the compiler both Authors and Books NSManagedObjects are just NSManagedObjects.

In summary, check that you are sending the correct NSManagedObject to the relationship as defined in the 'Destination' field.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `fkServerUpdatesToAuthors` will only accept NSSet object because it is a one-to-many relationship. You should try:

```
[updateObj setValue:[NSSet setWithObject:obj] forKey:@"fkServerUpdatesToAuthors"];
```

Comment: It's a to-one relationship as far as fkServerUpdatesToAuthors is concerned. I deleted the CoreData entity and re-built it and it started working with the above code, so I think something wasn't configured correctly in there. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this stupid message did show for me when those core data entities didn't have corresponding autogenerated files. When I did generate NSManagedObject's for each entity I have in xdatamodel, everything started working well.